# What does it mean. => in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anyone know the meaning for the following symbol in rails?

**=>**

```
def update
  account = Account.find params[:id]
  permitted = params.require(:account).permit(:name, :otherparam)
  account.update_attributes permitted
  render :json => account
end
```

for what purpose we need to use the above expression?

I have searched it in google. but no luck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ES6 Arrow Functions` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: short for `render: function(json){return account}`

Answer (score 0):

It is an old syntax for a hash. Just don't use it.
`{ hi: 'hola' }` is equivalent to `{ :hi => 'hola'}` but the first is preferred.

Comment: Did my answer help you? Does it need further explanation? If it helped you, it is customary to mark the answer as accepted.